# fbprophet failed to build wheel in google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, requirements.txt, facebook-prophet

I am hoping to use Fbprophet on my cloud function in a **Python 3.7 environment**, but it fails to build and gives me the following error.

```
Build failed: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-3_5khs54
    cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/fbprophet
    creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/setup.py", line 148, in <module>
    """
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 140, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
    self.run_command('build')
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/setup.py", line 48, in run
    build_models(target_dir)
    File "/tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/setup.py", line 36, in build_models
    from fbprophet.models import StanBackendEnum
    File "/tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/fbprophet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from fbprophet.forecaster import Prophet
    File "/tmp/pip-wheel-srnqu7b5/fbprophet/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 14, in <module>
    import numpy as np
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
    
    error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1; Error ID: 618AA8E7
```

This is what my `requirements.txt` file looks like:

```
cython
pystan
numpy
pandas==1.0.3
google-cloud-storage==1.29.0
fbprophet
geopy==1.22.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.25.0
```

Everything works perfectly fine locally in a Python 3.7 virtual environment on jupyter notebook. Would appreciate any help because I've spent almost an entire day trying to fix this but to no avail.

Comment: There is a similar issue to this one being discussed in this [prophet github issue](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1551 ). As you mention this works locally, maybe you could try [deploying the dependencies together with the function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#packaging_local_dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues to this. My goal is to deploy a function that, when passed some input, will feed this into a Prophet model in order to make a prediction before passing the prediction to another part of my system.

As far as I can tell, there are a few things that make this complicated.

First, there is the issue of build dependencies that @mgoya mentioned in the comment above. This manifests both when installing Prophet and when installing Pystan (a dependency of Prophet). In my `cloudbuild.yaml` I'm attempting to circumvent this by installing the dependencies in sequence, like this:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'docker.io/library/python:3.9'
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  # Run pip install and pytest in the same build step
  # (pip packages won't be preserved in future steps!)
  args: [-c, 'pip uninstall pystan; pip install convertdate==2.1.2 lunarcalendar==0.0.9 holidays==0.10.3 pgen tqdm cython pandas numpy setuptools; pip install pystan==2.19.1.1; pip install -r requirements.txt']
  timeout: 1200s
```

This first uninstalls Pystan (if one exists locally), then installs the build dependencies for Pystan (a build dependency for Prophet), then installs Prophet (which is included in my `requirements.txt`).

Note the semicolons. I ran into issues when using double-ampersands instead (i.e. `pip install ... && pip install ... etc.`. I *believe* this may be due to the way that the installed packages make their way to the local file system and are made available to the following commands. By running them with `&&` this seems to try and run them all at once, which won't give the earlier parts of the installation time to propagate and be discoverable by later steps. Using semicolons seems to help with this but it's anecdotal evidence at best.

You could also try using `python -m pip install ...` rather than `pip install` though I'm not familiar enough with Python to tell you the difference off the top of my head.

Secondly, there are the memory requirements for installing Pystan. I've read somewhere that Pystan requires 4GB of memory to install. The default `machine_type` for cloudbuild does not have that much. You can try increasing the size of the machine by [changing its type](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#machinetype).

Finally, there's the resources allocated for function execution. Again, I read somewhere that Prophet / Pystan require 2GB of memory just to run one of the models. So, if your cloud function doesn't have this, it may run into memory issues when trying to execute. In my experience so far, memory issues are not *that* transparent within Google Cloud.

--

My current thinking (and perhaps what I'd recommend to anyone else reading this post) is to consider whether Cloud Functions is the right tool for this, given the weight of the dependencies. Pystan and Prophet are rather special-case dependencies, given their build and runtime resource requirements.

What I've opted to do is build (locally) a container with these dependencies baked in and pushing this to Google's Container Registry. My plan from here is to use that container as the base image for a Cloud Run application, which is significantly easier to deploy. This has obvious drawbacks but if my base image changes infrequently (which it will) I think this approach would be fine. Unfortunately, this model ("bring your own container") is not supported by Cloud Functions - it's designed where all you bring is code.